# Developing in Qt for iOS on a Linux computer

Tags: ios, linux, qt

I'm planning to develop an app for Android using Qt Quick Controls and an Android Emulator. The same set of components is said to work on iOS. Thus I'd like to build the app for iOS as well.

Unfortunately, Qt for iOS is only available for Mac.

I don't own any Apple or Android device. I'm using a computer running Linux.

What would then be the best way to be able to build the app for iOS (and test whether everything works as expected; most testing will take place in the Android emulator)?

If any more information is needed, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: You need a Mac.  There is no getting away from it.  However building a Hackintosh and dual-booting with Linux would work too.

Comment: If you have a powerful enough machine, (not sooooo powerful if you only need to compile in Mac) you can use a virtualization software on your Linux. VirtualBox seems to be a good candidate as there are several tutorials on the web that shows how to install Mac OS X Yosemite in a VB virtual machine.

Comment: @trojanfoe you sure about that? I've built programs for iOS from linux before with a home-made toolchain.