# Building Qt apps for Windows Phone on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, qt, windows-phone

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285520/developing-in-qt-for-ios-on-a-linux-computer)

I'm planning to develop an app for Android using Qt Quick Controls and an Android Emulator. The same set of components is said to work on Windows Phone. Thus I'd like to build the app for Windows Phone as well.

Unfortunately, Qt for Windows Phone is only available for Windows.

I don't own any Windows phone. I'm using a computer running Linux.

Is it possible to build the app for Windows Phone and test it in an Emulator without virtualizing/dual-booting Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is **Wine**. This is what wikipedia says about it;

> Wine (short for **W**ine **I**s **N**ot an **E**mulator) is a free and open source compatibility layer software application that aims to allow applications designed for Microsoft Windows to run on Unix-like operating systems. Wine also provides a software library, known as **Winelib**, against which developers can compile Windows applications to help port them to Unix-like systems.

You can find more info about **Wine** here; https://www.winehq.org/

I haven't tried it before but since it says "allow applications designed for Microsoft Windows to run on Unix-like operating systems," I'm thinking it should work.

This is your only option. If it doesn't work, then i guess you should think about running windows on virtual machine or dual booting with windows. Good luck!